# How to swap adjacent images in HTML after an if statement

Tags: javascript, html

If I click on a picture next to the blank cell (either above, left, right or below it), it needs to swap the position of the cell I clicked on and the blank cell.

My table is 6x6 and I think I have the right methodology, but it isn't swapping...

The blank cell is called blank.jpg and every other cell is 01.jpg - 35.jpg

```
function move(n)
{
    var clickedImage = document.images[n].src;
    var leftImage    = document.images[n-01].src;
    var rightImage   = document.images[n+01].src;
    var upImage      = document.images[n-06].src;
    var downImage    = document.images[n+06].src;

    var leftNum  = leftImage.charAt(leftImage.length-5);
    var rightNum = rightImage.charAt(rightImage.length-5);
    var upNum    = upImage.charAt(upImage.length-5);
    var downNum  = downImage.charAt(downImage.length-5);

    if (isNan(leftNum))
    {
        a            = clickedImage
        b            = leftImage
        clickedImage = b
        leftImage    = a
    }
    else if (isNan(rightNum))
    {
        a            = clickedImage
        b            = rightImage
        clickedImage = b
        rightImage   = a
    }
    else if (isNan(upNum))
    {
        a            = clickedImage
        b            = upImage
        clickedImage = b
        upImage      = a
    }
    else if (isNan(downNum))
    {
        a            = clickedImage;
        b            = downImage;
        clickedImage = b;
        downImage    = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your charAt functions are missing the closing parentheses

Comment: Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Check the console(Ctrl+Shift+C) and see if there's any error?

Comment: Also, you can make use of HTML's tree structure for this.Take a look at this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778385/sliding-puzzle-for-javascript

Comment: @DanielTate I closed the parentheses. The errors I am getting are: 1. The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared: 3. ReferenceError: isNan is not defined

Comment: `isNan` -> `isNaN`

Comment: @connexo wow I can't believe I missed that. 0 errors now, but it still doesn't swap.

Comment: could you please create fiddle ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I don't know what that is

Comment: Add your JS , CSS, HTML content in https://jsfiddle.net/ and share that link